# Efficient way to delete document in mongoose with authentication

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm building a rest api with express and mongoose. This is the way I delete documents from a collection:

```js
...

if (!req.session.user) return res.status(401).send()
const e = await Event.findOne({_id: req.params.eventId}).exec();
if (e.owner !== req.session.user) return res.status(403).send();
await Event.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.eventId}).exec();
return res.status(204).send()

...
```

The problem I see is that I'm querying the database two times for a single document and doesn't looks right or efficient to me.

What is the correct way to do this with only one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass owner field in the delete query with owner set as the req.session.user and if there will be a document with an particular event id and owner as the session user it will be deleted.

```
if (!req.session.user) return res.status(401).send()
await Event.findOneAndDelete({_id: req.params.eventId, owner: req.session.user}).exec();
return res.status(204).send()
```

And, as mongodb does not have an internal support for RBAC at document level, there will be many use cases where you will have to make multiple queries for determining if a request is authorized to do certain things or not.
You can check out [Casl library](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/) for better RBAC management and it also has support for mongodb inbuilt.